# How to convert a groupby pandas object into a dataframe while integrating a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

i would like to transform a grouped dataframe into a dataframe object in the following way:

starting point is

[image]

finishing point is:

[image]

The point is to integrate the column number into category_a and category_b

one can of course reset_index and with a loop , get the values through all the df and construct it from scratch. however this is a tiny example, and my dataframe is way bigger than that, i was wondering whether there is an easier way to do this.

thanks

Comment: Looks like a `pivot` to me, or `.unstack()` if it is an index

Comment: thank you . unstack is exactly what I Want